# Is there a better way to fix npm vulnerabilities?

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo, native

I'm having a problem fixing the vulnerabilities in my expo react-native project.
It is a react-native app under development.

I keep getting this;

```
up to date, audited 1375 packages in 1m

73 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

18 vulnerabilities (10 moderate, 8 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Here's my `package.json` file;

```
{
  "name": "xxxxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "*",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "*",
    "expo": "^47.0.9",
    "expo-constants": "~14.0.2",
    "expo-contacts": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.1.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-location": "~15.0.1",
    "expo-sms": "~11.0.0",
    "expo-speech": "~11.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "firebase": "^9.16.0",
    "from": "^0.1.7",
    "native": "^0.3.3",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.8",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "*",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-maps-directions": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-paper": "4.9.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-sha256": "^1.4.9",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "reanimated-bottom-sheet": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.8"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I tried multiple solutions such as;

```
npm audit
npm audit fix
npm audit fix --force
npm update
npm upgrade
npx remove-node-modules
npm install
npm install --check
```

I also tried manually fixing the dependencies to make them compatible but to no avail.
In most cases, the errors only got worse.

By running `npx expo-doctor` however, this was the result;

```
$ npx expo-doctor

✔ Validating global prerequisites versions passed
✔ Checking for incompatible packages passed
✔ Checking for conflicting global packages in project passed
✔ Verifying prebuild support package versions are compatible passed
✔ Checking dependency versions for compatibility with the installed Expo SDK passed
✔ Validating Expo Config passed
✔ Checking package.json for common issues passed

Didn't find any issues with the project!
```

Yet the dependency errors still remain.

How can I fix the dependencies?

Comment: Yeah there is: installing the latest versions of all your dependencies, and finding replacements for dependencies that have security holes that haven't been updated in years or stopped being maintained altogether. `npm audit fix` is a temporary last resort while you make time to properly update your dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans . I have already tried updating my dependencies to their latest versions but it crushed the app so, I had to revert to the previous form. But, I'll have to find out if there are any replacements for the packages installed. Thanks again.

Comment: I fully appreciate how much of a pain updating an entire package.json can be, I've been there plenty of times myself, but it really is the only "real" way to fix security issues.

Comment: Note that sometimes you won't be able to fix _everything_ immediately because those fixes need be done by the maintainers of library x, y or z (which you use) which themselves have an out-of-date library as a dependency which needs to be fixed by _its_ maintainers.

Comment: Oh ok. That's clear. But isn't that problematic, since my app keeps crashing? Anyway, thank you @Andy

Comment: It is, one way to circumvent it is to use the package.json `overrides` option to force-install a specific, more modern version of a dependency-of-dependency, but you're never guaranteed that things will keep working when you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, there's no magic command to fix all the vulnerabilities in a project, as the project gets older and versions outdated security issues start raising. That said, how do we fix them?

The best way is to **upgrade your packages**.

Start by running `npm audit`, this will give you the full list of vulnerabilities, tell in which version it was patched and what package is using that dependency (labeled as `dependency of`), all you need to do is upgrade the package either with `npm install package-name` or manually setting the version in your `package.json` and then running npm install.

Repeat the process till you fix them all.

Now there's more way of fixing these vulnerabilities without upgrading the package, you can directly upgrade the dependency in the `package-lock.json`, however I don't recommend this way unless you're using a tool like *Dependabot*.

Comment: This is guaranteed not the _fastest_ way. It's the best way, by far, but if you work on a real project, with thousands of users and years of baggage, uplifting your dependencies is, realistically, weeks of work because you _can't_ uplift everything all at once. That will just break your entire codebase. No one in a dev team would put the rest of the team through that. It's going to be a slow and steady process.

Comment: Well once again it depends on your packages and the breaking changes, I fixed 200+ vulnerabilities on 3 different code bases (Entreprise level) in less than a week. However I agree with you that this might be very long process if your code base is big and really old and you didn't maintain it for years. What I mean by the fastest is, is faster than going through each dependency and update manually.

Comment: It doesn't even need to be big. It just needs to be old enough, with enough _interdependent_ packages.

Comment: Big as in more dependencies*, but yes, I get your point.

Comment: I changed it to "best" since speed is very relative and might be misleading, thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using npm update is a good solution, as it could bring in many breaking changes and might not actually update the packages of packages, which are what usually cause audit issues in the first place.  I also don't think adding the packages of packages to your package.json is good either.  One of the best reasons why is simple; you are not using them in your code, and it could easily be seen by another dev to be a not in use package, and they will remove it as part of general maintenance.  It doesn't usually fix the problem anyway.

I recently found the following to be my most preferable way of dealing with CVE's and audit problems when unable to just update the parent package to solve its children's issues.  Its also incredibly easy to do and fast.  Have spent an hour or so most doing it this way:

- Install nvm or some other node version manager.
- Delete the package.lock (due to namespace issues)
- Switch to node 14 (npm version 6 with the original, far better audit)
- Run npm install.
- Run npm v6 audit and fix issues using provided commands (Gives fix commands like `npm update package --depth=4`)
- Switch back to latest node version using nvm (Or whatever you are using)
- Run npm i to update the package lock version (Don't delete the package lock as that is where the fixes live)

Should also add, no version of npm audit catches everything.  Its actually pretty rubbish overall.  Its alternatives like Sandworm are no real good either.  They have prettier interfaces, but as they rely on the npm audit endpoints to check package vuns, they fall down in the same way.

If you have any docker experience however, I'd check out Docker scout. That WILL catch all reported CVE's, including from node_modules.  Unfortunately you have to figure out what package is causing them, but if you've also ran npm audit in the way I mentioned, it will only be a couple vuns most, as audit will have dealt with 95% of them.